# CharSequence[] to CharSequance

Tags: android, charsequence

I am using the library material dialogs. The multi list uses CharSequence[] instead of CharSequence.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, Integer[] which, CharSequence[] text) {

     // If Bold//
     if (text.equals("Bold") {

     }
}
```

Because it is  CharSequence[] and not  CharSequence I can't get the text value. How do I get the text value out of CharSequence[]. Here is the link to the library if that helps :)

https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Comment: You have to define what you mean by "the" text value of a `CharSequence[]`.  Would it be the concatenation of all the elements of the array, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call back your posted is for "Multi Choice List" which means there are multiple options that are returned in your call back in `which` array and `text` array.

text is an array so you can get text of first choice like this:

```
text[0]
```

Same way you can check `which`:

```
which[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using multiselection. You have text[0], text[1], text[2]...
If there is only one choice then text[0].toString() is your text value

Comment: Thank You Also Both Worked Very Well!